# JPA one-to-one mapping gives sax parse exception

Tags: jpa, orm, one-to-one

I'm getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException's when trying to map a one-to-one relation in JPA

Everything is working fine until I change from

> `<transient name="testCase"/>`

to:

```
<attributes>
..
    <one-to-one name="testCase">
        <join-column name="test_case_id"/>
    </one-to-one>
..
</attributes>
```

Gives error:

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'one-to-one'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":many-to-many, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":embedded, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":transient}' is expected.

I don't understand what the exception message means. Why is these expected for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your orm.xml was not valid according to it's XML Schema. The problem was that the element 'one-to-one' is part of a sequence, which means that the contained elements MUST respect the defined order.

An abstract of the Schema:

```xml
  <xsd:complexType name="attributes">
    <xsd:sequence>
      ...
      <xsd:element name="basic" .../>
      <xsd:element name="version" .../>
      <xsd:element name="many-to-one" .../>
      <xsd:element name="one-to-many" .../>
      <xsd:element name="one-to-one" .../>
      <xsd:element name="many-to-many" .../>
      ...
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

see the whole Schema at [enter link description here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd)

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.  I moved the one-to-one section so it was before the many-to-many section. Don't know why this happened. The two sections does not have anything in common.